# Can I use 'his this' in a sentence?

Tags: relative-pronouns, possessives

*He is in danger.Tie this ribbon to **his this** hand for his safety.*

Is it correct?

Comment: It could be either word but not both. "his" refers to which person, and "this" refers to which hand. It depends on what you are trying to say.

Comment: Incorrect grammatically. You can say "Tie this ribbon to this hand of his for his safety, tie this ribbon to his right/left hand for his safety, or tie this ribbon to this right/left hand of his for his safety".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not grammatically correct.  As used in the original poster's example, "his" and "this" are both determiners, with conflicting meanings.  Zero or one determiners can be used with a noun like "hand".  As probablyme suggests, adjectives can be used to describe other aspects of the noun.

Comment: Why can't "this" just be an adjective? Must it be a delimiter? I'm asking for knowledge.

Comment: @probablyme Because it is "this" but not "that". The left hand but not the right hand.

Comment: @probablyme A very good question, indeed!

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**
<strike>I believe it is grammatical,</strike> It might not be grammatical. According to Jasper, it isn't. The sentence sounds like something a child might say. A child might not remember left from right, so would refer to it as his "this" hand. It's also possible that you are pointing to your own hand and calling it "this" hand. But it really needs more context to be understood that way.

I would recommend a different adjective, like his "right hand" or his "left hand".

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard of *his this hand* being grammatical.

But *this his hand* or *that my answer* are "marginally" grammatical in today's English, being fully grammatical 400 years ago in early modern English–and possibly more recent than that. I wouldn't recommend it for a test of English, but you could get by with it in other contexts.

Example from *[The life of Benjamin Franklin](https://books.google.com/books?id=EAQFAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA41&dq="this+his"&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_4vTY0bfNAhUIrD4KHasdAZE4WhDoAQg0MAQ#v=onepage&q=%22this%20his%22&f=false)* (1835):

> Encouraged by such good  success of this his first adventure, he wrote on, and sent to the press, in the same sly way, several other pieces...

Comment: Are you referring to questions like "Is this his hand?" or "Is that your answer?"

Comment: @Alan you could've used quoted in your answer some of those older usage where it says *"this his hand"* and similar things. I also believe that it was once in use. And in today's version of English it's entirely ungrammatical/wrong.

Comment: @Jasper I don't think he meant that. There are indeed some evidence that says it's once in use. For example - *"The queen is dead. God save the King. In this his hour of grief."* [Year - 1905]. He could have included similar quotation in his answers, because it's such strange thing to consider something correct.

Comment: In Spanish we still use the equivalent of that phrase, "this his first adventure", but to be fair, you could only hear it on speeches or when you want to be very formal. We made a litte pause betweem "this" and "his" to emphasize what we are talking about, "his first adventure". Even, we write a comma between those words, writing in Spanish "such good success of this, his first adventure". HTH

Answer (score 1):

.....his this hand.

The sentence is incorrect grammatically.  You can't put a determiner between a possessive determiner and a noun. Instead, you can use the following structure:

Determiner + noun + of possessive.

For example, Did you see this car of Peter's?

So you can say:

Tie this ribbon to this hand of his for his safety.

But the use of 'his right hand/left hand' is more appropriate.

.